# Post deleted in trash

Tags: plugins, posts, trash

I need a plugin or some method to recover deleted post of trash.

Answer (score 1):

Once a post is moved to the trash and deleted, it's gone from the database. The only way to recover it is from an earlier database backup. Do you have a backup? Does your webhost have a backup?